# Take screenshot of a file opened in Selenium browser

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am downloading a pdf file with Selenium browser and I need a screenshot of it. The simplest method that I thought was to open it in the browser (Chrome) and take a screenshot with the driver. But, the issue is that the screenshot is empty, with a gray background

Am I missing something? Isn't Selenium Chromedriver able to take a screenshot of a file opened in browser?

Some code that I use:

```
driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab);
                        
Thread.Sleep(1000);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(file);

ITakesScreenshot screenshot = driver as ITakesScreenshot;

Screenshot screenshotObj = screenshot.GetScreenshot();

screenshotObj.SaveAsFile(filePath, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: If you have a PDF file, why don't you use PDF tools to get the page?  Are these PDFs of scanned pages?

Comment: It was just because of simplicity and not mix things up. I thought that selenium already has this functionality. And also, because the browser is of custom size, and screenshot needs to be of custom size

Comment: Remember that Selenium operates asynchronously in real-time.  `GoToUrl` returns long before the file has been received.  You might add a multi-second sleep and see if that helps things.

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you
I added 5 seconds sleep and the screenshot is alright. Please post this as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Selenium operates asynchronously in real-time. `GoToUrl` returns long before the file has been received. You might add a multi-second sleep and see if that helps things.